# How do I make a timer continue after I reset myself in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a timer to continue AFTER the game resets itself and still have the same time, right now, every time my character resets it resets the timer. I am doing this in C# in a 3D Unity game. I have looked at lots of videos and lots of websites and no one seems to have the answer. this is my code:

```
 void Dying()
    {
        Invoke("LoadFirstLevel", Delay);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Obstacle":
                LoadFirstLevel();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void LoadFirstLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
```

This is my timer code:

```
{
    float currentTime = 0f;
    float startingTime = 60f;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    [SerializeField] Text CountdownText;
    void Start()`enter code here`
    {
        currentTime = startingTime;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        CountdownText.text = currentTime.ToString("0");

        if (currentTime <= 0)
        {
            currentTime = 0;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DontDestroyOnLoad` to your timer object. It prevent your object destroying when a scene is changed.

```cs
void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

or you can use static variables to your time count. It also  remains the value.

Comment: Then you would need a Singleton pattern .. otherwise you will get multiple parallel instances every time you reload the same scene...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `static` field so it is "shared" among all instances of this class - sessionwide!

You could combine it with a second `static bool` flag for indicating whether the field was initialized before so it is **not** reset to `60` later but only the first time:

```c#
private static float currentTime = 0f;
// This could even be a constant
private const float startingTime = 60f;
private static bool isInitialized;

AudioSource audioSource;

[SerializeField] Text CountdownText;
void Start()
{
    // Use the flag so this is only done once for this session
    if(!isInitialized)
    {
        currentTime = startingTime;
        isInitialized = true;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    currentTime -= * Time.deltaTime;
    CountdownText.text = currentTime.ToString("0");

    if (currentTime <= 0)
    {
        currentTime = 0;
    }
}
```

Now every instance of your timer decreases the same `currentTime` field.